# Why discarding the linear combination of solutions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, superposition, linear-systems

In Griffiths's textbook (Introduction to quantum mechanics), part I, 4.1.2, he's solving Schrodinger equation in three dimensions, after separating the variables $Y(\theta, \phi) = \Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)$, he obtained the equation
$$\frac{d^2 \Phi}{d \phi^2} = -m^2\Phi$$
but he only gave the solution $\Phi(\phi)=e^{im\phi}$, and the book says it will cover the conjugate solution $\Phi(\phi)=e^{-im\phi}$ if we allow $m$ to run negative, but, my question is that, the linear combination of these two solutions cannot be covered in this trick while it's also a valid solution

Are there anything I'm missing? or any restrictions that make the linear combination invalid?

Comment: What do you mean? If you have two (linearly independent) eigenfunctions both with the same eigenvalue, then any linear combination is an eigenfunction with the same eigenvalue, indeed. But this is true for any eigenvalue problem. So what exactly is your question here? What do you mean with "discarding"? Can you clarify?

Comment: There are two reasons to ignore linear combinations. Firstly, nobody is claiming that linear combinations are invalid; instead, the point to note is that after solving these simplest systems, the final solution will be linear combinations of all the simpler solutions, so there is not only no need to go out of your way to consider linear combinations at this current stage, but that you should actively go for simplicity, leaving generality for later. The second argument is that your linear combination choice will fail to be simultaneously diagonal in the commuting set $H$ and $L_z$ operators.

Comment: In the context of the book, I'm solving the differential equation analytically, I think I'm finding the general solution for Schrodinger equation in three dimensions, or do you mean the author is trying to find the eigenfunctions?

Comment: It is much simpler than you think. I am just saying that we are looking for solutions that are simultaneous eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian operator $\hat{\mathcal H}$ and the z-component of the orbital angular momentum operator $\hat L_z$. The latter of which only accepts $e^{im\varphi}$ but rejects linear combinations of them.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I got your point, I was simply focusing on solving the equation, but missed the limitations of physics

Comment: It is not a limitation at all. This is a general method. You can get all possible solutions by following this scheme.

Comment: but you just said to guarantee the Hamiltonian and z-component of orbital angular momentum are commutative, is this not a limitation?

Comment: Saying that you want "all solutions" is, in some sense, useless. If you have an eigenvector $v$, then $cv$ with any $c\neq 0$ is an eigenvector to the same eigenvalue too. What you are interested in QM is basically always a complete (orthonormal) basis of eigenvectors and this is not unique in any case (you can e.g. scale any vector by a phase). Additionally, if you have degeneracies, then you have a whole vector subspace, called the eigenspace, of eigenvectors. There, you want to make suitable choices, as @naturallyInconsistent points out (e.g. also eigenbasis of other operators).

Comment: @Arthur, the Hamiltonian operator commutes with any single component of the orbital angular momentum operator. This is a fact, both mathematical and experimental, and is not at all a limitation. We are simply choosing to respect this commutation relation in the choice of the eigenfunction, and that is again not a limitation.